# Understanding Ruby Code

Tags: ruby

I need some help understanding the below ruby code.

```
counted = Hash.new(0)
parsed_reponse["result"]["data"].each { |h| counted[h["version"]] += 1 }
counted = Hash[counted.map {|k,v| [k,v.to_s] }]
```

- I understand line 1 creats a hash which I believe is similar to a
  dictionary in python.
- Line 2 loops through my json data set a adds a
  new key and value pair if none exits and increments the count if 1
  does exist.
- What does the 3rd line do?

Comment: [`Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] → new_hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) -- Creates a new hash populated with the given objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line just converts all values to String:

```
Hash[{a: 2, b: 3}.map {|k, v| [k, v.to_s]}]
#=> {:a=>"2", :b=>"3"}
```

I would refactor it to:

```
counted.transform_values!(&:to_s) # for ruby >= 2.4
#=> {:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}
```

Or for older versions:

```
counted.each { |k, v| counted[k] = v.to_s }
```

Because:

- `counted.map {|k,v| [k,v.to_s] }` - creates new array of arrays
- `Hash[result]` - creates new Hash object from `result` array.

Both steps are redundant, you can just modify existing hash.

Comment: Is there documentation for .map. method. I tried looking here, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html, but found nothing.

Comment: In recent Ruby versions you could write `counted.transform_values!(&:to_s)`